# Toolbar shadow not showing

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, appbar, android-elevation

My app has a fragment with tablayout and it shows a shadow with elevation:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
 android:id="@+id/my_music_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_bg"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/color_tab_text_selected"
    app:tabTextColor="?attr/color_tab_text"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/color_tab_text_selected"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />
```

But when I switch to another fragment that doesn't have a TabLayout, the shadow doesn't appear:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:expanded="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false" >

        <include
            layout="@layout/imageview_appbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by adding the following codes to my MainActivity class:

```
    AppBarLayout layout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    layout.setStateListAnimator(null);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(layout, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Appbarlayout doesn't display shadow if it contains a scrollable collapsing toolbar, it is hardcoded to act so, probably because of performance concerns.

Try workarounds such as adding a plain view to bottom of appbar and setting its background to a shadow drawable ( manually coded gray gradient )